# convert an array of objects to other array of objects with more key-value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a scenario where I need to convert below array of objects into other array of objects like below:

given array:

```
let a = [{value : 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 7}, {value: 9}];
let b = [{name : dataA}, {name: dataB}, {name: dataC}, {name: dataD}]
```

Final output needed::

```
let c = [{value:2, name: dataA},{value:4, name: dataB},{value:7, name: dataC},{value:9, name: dataD}]
```

I am confused how to do it like this.

Comment: Please check out my answer. If it solves your problem please consider to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Any questions on my answer @user12893845? Any of the methods should do it. If I helped - Please consider to mark it as the accepted answer and up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with reduce:

```js
let a = [{value : 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 7}, {value: 9}];
let b = [{name : 'dataA'}, {name: 'dataB'}, {name: 'dataC'}, {name: 'dataD'}]

const output = a.reduce((aggArr, child, index) => {
  child.name = b[index].name;
  aggArr.push(child)
  return aggArr;
}, [])

console.log(output);
```

You could also do it with map:

```js
let a = [{value : 2}, {value: 4}, {value: 7}, {value: 9}];
let b = [{name : 'dataA'}, {name: 'dataB'}, {name: 'dataC'}, {name: 'dataD'}]

const output = a.map((child, index) => {
  child.name = b[index].name;
  return child;
})

console.log(output);
```

You could also do it more generally so that any and all key, value pairs would be merged together, and in case of a collision save an array of values.

That would look like (with more complex initial data):

```js
let a = [
  {value : 2, letter: 'a'},
  {value: 4, letter: 'b'},
  {value: 7, letter: 'c'},
  {value: 9, letter: 'd'}
];
let b = [
  {value: 4, name : 'dataA'},
  {value: 6, name: 'dataB'},
  {value: 14, name: 'dataC'},
  {value: 18, name: 'dataD'}
]

const output = a.map((child, index) => {
  Object.keys(b[index]).forEach(key => {
    if (child.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      child[key] = [child[key], b[index][key]];
    } else{
      child[key] = b[index][key];
    }
  });
  return child;
})

console.log(output);
```

Output is:

```
output = [
  {value : [2, 4], letter: 'a', name : 'dataA'},
  {value: [4, 8], letter: 'b', name : 'dataB'},
  {value: [7, 14], letter: 'c', name : 'dataC'},
  {value: [9, 18], letter: 'd', name : 'dataD'}
];
```

If you don't care about collisions or they will never happen then you can simplify this:

```js
let a = [
  {value : 2, letter: 'a'},
  {value: 4, letter: 'b'},
  {value: 7, letter: 'c'},
  {value: 9, letter: 'd'}
];
let b = [
  {value: 4, name : 'dataA'},
  {value: 6, name: 'dataB'},
  {value: 14, name: 'dataC'},
  {value: 18, name: 'dataD'}
]

const output = a.map((child, index) => {
  return Object.assign(child, b[index]);
})

console.log(output);
```

So notice how the collision is handled:

Output is:

```
output = [
  {value : 4, letter: 'a', name : 'dataA'},
  {value: 8, letter: 'b', name : 'dataB'},
  {value: 14, letter: 'c', name : 'dataC'},
  {value: 18, letter: 'd', name : 'dataD'}
];
```

i.e. the second array's values overwrite the first's

Also important to know is that `Object.assign()` is supported since Edge 12 but it is not supported in IE at all - but of course it is supported in all major browsers:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_object_assign

Finally, we could also replace `return Object.assign(child, b[index])` with `return {...child, ...b[index]}` but the support for this is not as good (although again all modern broswers support it):

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_operators_spread_spread_in_object_literals